# Analyze longitudinal data with a mixed effects model in R

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I try to analyze some simulated longitudinal data in R using a mixed-effects model (`lme4` package).

Simulated data: 25 subjects have to perform 2 tasks at 5 consecutive time points.

```
#Simulate longitudinal data
N    <- 25
t    <- 5
x    <- rep(1:t,N)

#task1
beta1 <- 4
e1    <- rnorm(N*t, mean = 0, sd = 1.5)
y1    <- 1 + x * beta1 + e1

#task2
beta2 <- 1.5
e2    <- rnorm(N*t, mean = 0, sd = 1)
y2    <- 1 + x * beta2 + e2

data1 <- data.frame(id=factor(rep(1:N, each=t)), day = x, y = y1, task=rep(c("task1"),length(y1)))
data2 <- data.frame(id=factor(rep(1:N, each=t)), day = x, y = y2, task=rep(c("task2"),length(y2)))
data <- rbind(data1, data2)
```

**Question1**: How to analyze how a subject learns each task?

```
library(lme4)
m1 <- lmer(y ~ day + (1 | id), data=data1)
summary(m1)

...
Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1.2757     0.3561 123.0000   3.582 0.000489 ***
day           3.9299     0.1074 123.0000  36.603  < 2e-16 ***
```

With `ranef(m1)` I get the random intercept for each subject, which I think reflects the baseline value for each subject at day = 1. But I don't understand how I can tell how an individual learns a task, or whether subjects differ in the way how they learn the task.

**Question2:** How can I analyze whether the way subjects learn differ between task1 and task2.

Answer (score 4):

I expanded on your example to answer your questions briefly, but I can recommend reading chapter 15 of [Snijders & Bosker (2012)](https://books.google.nl/books?id=N1BQvcomDdQC&lpg=PP1&dq=snijders%20bosker%20multilevel&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=snijders%20bosker%20multilevel&f=false) or the book by [Singer & Willet (2003)](https://books.google.nl/books?id=eDWG3728OxcC&lpg=PP1&dq=singer%20willett%20longitudinal&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=singer%20willett%20longitudinal&f=false) for a better explanation. Day is treated as a continuous variable in your model, seeing as you have panel data (i.e. everyone is measured at the same day) and day has no meaning apart from indicating the different measurement occasions, it may be better to treat day as a factor (i.e. use dummy variables).
However, for now I will continue with your example

Your first model (I think you want data instread of data1) gives a fixed linear slope (i.e. average slope, no difference in the tasks, no difference between individuals). The fixed intercept is the performance when day is 0, which has no meaning so you may want to consider centering the effect of day for a better interpretation (or indeed use dummies). The random effect gives the individual deviance from this intercept which has an estimated variance of 0.00 in your example so individuals hardly differ from each other in their starting position.

```
m1 <- lmer(y ~ day + (1 | id), data=data)
summary(m1)
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept)  0.00    0.000   
 Residual             18.54    4.306   
Number of obs: 250, groups:  id, 25
```

We can extend this model by adding an interaction with task. Meaning that the fixed slope is different for task1 and task2 which answers question 2 I believe (you can also use `update()` to update your model)

```
m2 <- lmer(y ~ day*task + (1|id), data = data)
summary(m2)
```

The effect of day in this model is the fixed slope of your reference category (task1) and the interaction is the difference between the slope of task1 and task2. The fixed effect of task is the difference in intercept.
model fit can be assessed with a deviance test, read Snijders & Boskers (2012) for an explanation of ML and REML estimates.

```
anova(m1,m2)
```

To add a random effect for the growth of individuals we can update the model again, which answers question 1

```
m3 <- lmer(y ~ day*task + (day|id), data = data)
summary(m3)
ranef(m3)
```

The random effects indicate the individual deviations in slope and intercept. A summary of the distribution of you random effects is included in the model summary (same as for m1).
Finally I think you could add a random effect on the day-task interaction to assess whether individuals differ in their performance growth on task1 and task2. But this depends very much on your data and the performance of the previous models.

```
m4 <- lmer(y ~ day*task + (day*task|id), data = data)
summary(m4)
ranef(m4)
```

Hope this helps. The books I recommended certainly should. Both provide excellent examples and explanation of theory (no R examples unfortunately). If you decide on a fixed occasion model (effect of day expressed by dummies) the `nlme` package provides excellent options to control the covariance structure of random effects. Good documentation of the package is provided by [Pinheiro & Bates (2000)](https://books.google.nl/books?id=3TVDAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PR3&dq=pinheiro%20en%20bates&pg=PR1#v=onepage&q=pinheiro%20en%20bates&f=false).