# fitting a lmer with longitudinal data for 2 categorical predictors

Tags: r, linear-regression, lme4, mixed-models, longitudinal

I've seen many lmers , but not so many of them of longitudinal data (which is my case right now). The thing is,
I have scores (outcome) collected at 2021 and at 2022 (predictor: Year) and in two languages (Spanish and English, predictor: Language). Therefore, my data look like this:

```
SUBJECT SCORE YEAR LANGUAGE

SUBJ01  200   2021  SPANISH
SUBJ01  250   2022  ENGLISH
SUBJ01  230   2021  SPANISH
SUBJ01  300   2022  ENGLISH
.
.
.
```

So each subject has 4 scores, 2 per year (2021/2022) and 2 per language (Span/Eng). I'm fitting a lmer but I'm wondering if I should include random slopes as well or stay with random intercepts.

So, basically, I'm thinking about:

```
lmer(SCORE ~ YEAR * LANGUAGE + (1|SUBJECT), data = data)
```

or

```
lmer(SCORE ~ YEAR * LANGUAGE + (1|SUBJECT)+ (1|YEAR:SUBJECT) + (1|LANGUAGE:SUBJECT)
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024888/analyze-longitudinal-data-with-a-mixed-effects-model-in-r) help? Also this question may be better suited to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) as it's more about model specification than R code.

Comment: @neilfws, thank you, but I'm still wondering if I should use the random slopes or not...any thoughts on it? ps: I'll look for Cross Validaded